# HTTP status 500. java.lang.NullPointerException when I link other page with datatable

Tags: hibernate, jsf

Hello I'm newbie in hibernate, PrimeFaces, JSF and Spring. I'm trying make a code that it works.

I have Empresa.java, `EmpresaDAOImpl`, `EmpresaServiceImpl`, `EmpresaBean`. This code shows me in screen a datatable with radiobutton in each row and it works. Now I have implemented new classes, LDiario.java, `LDiarioDAOImpl`, `LDiarioServiceImpl` and `LDIarioBean`. `Empresa` and `Ldiario` has got a relationship oneToMany. But I don´t know how to make when i push the button in `Empresa` List goes to other page and show me other datatable `Ldiario`. Sorry I´m learning english. Thankyou very much.

**Error**

```
Grave: Error Rendering View[/pages/menu/menuPrincipal.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /pages/menu/menuPrincipal.xhtml @17,70 value="#{ldiarioBean.getLDiarioList()}": java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
```

**Empresa.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresas")
public class Empresa implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "empresa")  
private List<LDiario> ldiarios;
```

**LDiario.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LDIARIO2014")
public class LDiario implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;  

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn (name = "empresa") 
private Empresa empresa;
```

**EmpresaBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="empresaBean")
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class EmpresaBean {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;
    private Empresa empresa;
    private Empresa selectedEmpresa;


    public EmpresaService getEmpresaService() {
        return empresaService;
    }

    public Empresa getSelectedEmpresa() {
        return selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setSelectedEmpresa(Empresa selectedEmpresa) {
        this.selectedEmpresa = selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresaService(EmpresaService empresaService) {
        this.empresaService = empresaService;
    }

    public EmpresaBean(){
    }

    public List<Empresa> getEmpresaList(){

        return empresaService.getAll();
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }
    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }  

    public String View() {

        return "/pages/menu/menuPrincipal?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

**LDiarioBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="ldiarioBean")
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class LDiarioBean {

    private LDiario ldiario;
    @Autowired
    private LDiarioService ldiarioservice;

    private LDiario selectedLdiario;

    public LDiarioService getLdiarioservice() {
        return ldiarioservice;
    }
    public void setLDiarioservice(LDiarioService ldiarioservice) {
        this.ldiarioservice = ldiarioservice;
    }

    public LDiarioBean(){

    }
    public LDiario getLdiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }
    public void setLdiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    } 
    public LDiario getSelectedLdiario() {
        return selectedLdiario;
    }
    public void setSelectedLdiario(LDiario selectedLdiario) {
        this.selectedLdiario = selectedLdiario;
    }    

    public List<LDiario> getLDiarioList(){  
        return ldiarioservice.getAll();
    }

    public LDiario getLDiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }
    public void setLDiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    } 
}
```

**EmpresaServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Repository
public class EmpresaServiceImpl implements EmpresaService {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaDao empresaDao;

    @Override
    public List<Empresa> getAll() {
        return empresaDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

**LDiarioServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
@Repository
public class LDiarioServiceImpl implements LDiarioService {

    @Autowired
    private LDiarioDao ldiarioDao;

    @Override
    public List<LDiario> getAll() {
        return ldiarioDao.findAll();
    }
```

**EmpresaDAOImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class EmpresaDaoImpl implements EmpresaDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Empresa> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Empresa").list();
    }
}
```

**LDiarioDAOImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class LDiarioDaoImpl implements LDiarioDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<LDiario> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LDiario").list();
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
   <h:head>
      <title>Lista con Java Server Faces</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body> 

      <h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="radioDT"  var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"  
                selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">



    <f:facet name="header">
            Lista de Empresas
         </f:facet>
         <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
      <p:column headerText="Id">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.CLAVE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="Nombre Empresa">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.NOMBRE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="AÑO">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.EJERCICIO}" />
       </p:column>

       <!-- "#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" -->
<f:facet name="footer">

    <p:commandButton action="#{empresaBean.View}" value="Seleccionar" title="Ir Menu" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}" >
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{empresaBean.empresa}" value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

**menuPrincipal.xhtml** (The error in this page)

```
<h:form>
    <!--   <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.empresa}" />  -->

    <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" /> 

        <p:dataTable   var="ld" value="#{ldiarioBean.getLDiarioList()}">
        <!-- selection="#{ldiarioBean.selectedLdiario}" rowKey="#{ld.CLAVE}" -->

        <f:facet name="header">
            Listado Diario
         </f:facet>
         <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
      <p:column headerText="ASIENTO">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.ASIENTO}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="FECHA">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.FECHA}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="SUBCUENTA">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.SUBCUENTA}" />
       </p:column>

           <p:column headerText="CONCEPTO">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.CONCEPTO}" />
       </p:column>

           <p:column headerText="DEBE">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.DEBE}" />
       </p:column>

           <p:column headerText="HABER">
       <h:outputText value="#{ld.HABER}" />
       </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

[image]

I think that error is in LDiarioDAO.java in

```
@Override
    public List<LDiario> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LDiario").list();
    }
```

but i don´t know the solution. Can you help me please? I have looking for in this page 
https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/07/02/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Please do not abuse annotations (as I was also doing in the past :)). Have either Spring or JSF manage your beans. These are duplicate annotations `@ManagedBean(name="empresaBean")` and `@Component`. Use either of them (i.e. have either Spring or JSF manage your beans) with appropriate scoping mechanisms (Spring does not recognize the view scope. You would need to create your own custom (view) scope, if you happened to use Spring).