# How to access the database OneToMany Hibernate and show datatable?

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I have a database on localhost FirebirdSQL . I have two classes Empresa.java and LDIario.java it OneToMany relationship . How I can access  LDIario.java  data through Empresa.java in a new datatable in xhtml.I can access Empresa.java with EmpresaDaoImpl  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Empresa").list(); but i don´t know if is ok in LDiarioDAOImpl sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LDiario").list(); Sorry I´m learning english. Thank you very much.
Empresa------>LDiario

**Empresa.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "empresas")
public class Empresa implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "empresa")  
private List<LDiario> ldiarios;
```

**LDiario.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LDIARIO2014")
public class LDiario implements Serializable{

@Id 
@Column(name = "CLAVE")
@GeneratedValue private Integer CLAVE;  

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn (name = "empresa") 
private Empresa empresa;
```

**EmpresaBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="empresaBean")
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class EmpresaBean {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;
    private Empresa empresa;
    private Empresa selectedEmpresa;


    public EmpresaService getEmpresaService() {
        return empresaService;
    }

    public Empresa getSelectedEmpresa() {
        return selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setSelectedEmpresa(Empresa selectedEmpresa) {
        this.selectedEmpresa = selectedEmpresa;
    }

    public void setEmpresaService(EmpresaService empresaService) {
        this.empresaService = empresaService;
    }

    public EmpresaBean(){
    }

    public List<Empresa> getEmpresaList(){

        return empresaService.getAll();
    }

    public Empresa getEmpresa() {
        return empresa;
    }
    public void setEmpresa(Empresa empresa) {
        this.empresa = empresa;
    }  

    public String View() {

        return "/pages/menu/menuPrincipal?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}
```

**LDiarioBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name="ldiarioBean")
@ViewScoped
@Component
public class LDiarioBean {

    private LDiario ldiario;
    @Autowired
    private LDiarioService ldiarioservice;

    private LDiario selectedLdiario;

    public LDiarioService getLdiarioservice() {
        return ldiarioservice;
    }
    public void setLDiarioservice(LDiarioService ldiarioservice) {
        this.ldiarioservice = ldiarioservice;
    }

    public LDiarioBean(){

    }
    public LDiario getLdiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }
    public void setLdiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    } 
    public LDiario getSelectedLdiario() {
        return selectedLdiario;
    }
    public void setSelectedLdiario(LDiario selectedLdiario) {
        this.selectedLdiario = selectedLdiario;
    }    

    public List<LDiario> getLDiarioList(){  
        return ldiarioservice.getAll();
    }

    public LDiario getLDiario() {
        return ldiario;
    }
    public void setLDiario(LDiario ldiario) {
        this.ldiario = ldiario;
    } 
}
```

**LDiarioDAOImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class LDiarioDaoImpl implements LDiarioDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<LDiario> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from LDiario").list();
    }
}
```

**EmpresaDAOImpl.java**

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class EmpresaDaoImpl implements EmpresaDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Empresa> findAll() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Empresa").list();
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
   <h:head>
      <title>Lista con Java Server Faces</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body> 

      <h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="radioDT"  var="emp" value="#{empresaBean.getEmpresaList()}"  
                selection="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}">



    <f:facet name="header">
            Lista de Empresas
         </f:facet>
         <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
      <p:column headerText="Id">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.CLAVE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="Nombre Empresa">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.NOMBRE}" />
       </p:column>

         <p:column headerText="AÑO">
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.EJERCICIO}" />
       </p:column>

       <!-- "#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" -->
<f:facet name="footer">

    <p:commandButton action="#{empresaBean.View}" value="Seleccionar" title="Ir Menu" rowKey="#{emp.CLAVE}" >
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{empresaBean.empresa}" value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

**menuPrincipal.xhtml** (The error in this page)

```
<h:form>
    <!--   <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.empresa}" />  -->

    <h:outputText value="#{empresaBean.selectedEmpresa}" /> 

        <p:dataTable   var="ld" value="#{empresaBean.empresa.ldiarios}">
    <!-- selection="#{ldiarioBean.selectedLdiario}" rowKey="#{ld.CLAVE}" -->

    <f:facet name="header">
        Listado Diario
     </f:facet>
     <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>         
  <p:column headerText="ASIENTO">
   <h:outputText value="#{ld.ASIENTO}" />
   </p:column>
```

Is Ok empresaBean.empresa.ldiarios? What would you write? Thx.

Comment: You have not yet listened to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547822/http-status-500-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-i-link-other-page-with-data#comment43524319_27547822). You are mixing things in an incorrect assumption that both the frameworks JSF and Spring understand each other. You cannot succeed unless you have either Spring or JSF manage your beans - not both - no, they do not understand each other. I already faced this kind of situations before.

Comment: Ok thanks , I have to remove @Component , but I have to remove other annotations ? Or the rest is correct ? Thank you very much .

Comment: Nope. Your code implies that you are using Spring everywhere (or at least you are interested in Spring). If it is that then, you should have your beans managed by Spring and remove JSF related annotations like `@ManagedBean` (not `@Component`, you should actually be using its specialization `@Controller` instead). Spring does not support view scope out of  the box. You will need to create your own custom view scope. See [**1**](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=702), [**2**](http://blog.harezmi.com.tr/spring-view-scope-for-jsf-2-users/). Some versions might support it but I have not yet seen it.

Comment: Some people say that implementing a view scope in that way breaks some functionality after certain number of view scoped beans are created. I am not sure about that statement but in my application (that uses Spring 4.0 GA, Spring Security 3.2.0 GA, JSF 2.2.8-02, Hibernate 4.3.7 final), there are over 200 beans being managed by Spring in addition to other DAO/DTO and utility classes, many of them view scoped which is implemented in that way. The application goes just fine everywhere until now.

Comment: Ok, only question, Can i use primefaces without jsf?

Comment: No. PrimeFaces itself is not a framework like JSF. Rather it is a component library built on top of the JSF framework. Hence, it cannot be isolated from JSF. You can understand PrimeFaces as an extension of JSF that supports a set of rich components rendering HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: Can i use jsr-3300 how this page? http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/  .?

Comment: I choose to remain silent about that link because the article was written by mkyoung - a well-know name :). Just put something into practice and ask questions here, if there is a **specific problem** and you are certain that you have tried enough to solve the problem(s).

Comment: Ok , I'll modify the code to make a datatable what you recommend jquery or other ? Thx by the information. :) I would like something easi how primefaces.